# Qt for Android and gRPC

Tags: android, c++, qt, qml, grpc

I want to compile and use gRPC C++ client with my Qt/QML application for Android and iOS. I have several problem when compiling gRPC lib (but not protocol buffer), so, before spending a lot of time, I want to ask if it isn't possible to use gRPC C++ client with Qt for Android and iOS target ?

Comment: There is a code path that detects and possibly works on Android, and we have heard success stories compiling and using gRPC C++ on Android, but that code path is not actively maintained, and we do not have continuous integration tests running for it; therefore it is unsupported and things may break at any time. We do, however, welcome patches to fix potential issues related to that.